# How to call super class constructor from Nth sub class

Tags: php, class, constructor, call, super

I want to  know how can i call constructor of super parent class from Nth (2nd or 3rd or Any) sub class.

```
class a{
    public function __construct(){
        echo "<br>In constructor of class A <br>";
    }
}
class b extends a {
    public function __construct(){
        echo "<br>In constructor of class B <br>";
    }
}
class c extends b {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        echo "<br>In constructor of class C <br>";
    }       
}
$obj = new c;
```

What changes i need to make in constructor of class C above where parent's constructor is being called. Parent:: __construct(); referes to consructor of Class B where as i need to call constructor of class A from class C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way for you to call `class a`'s constructor from `class c` using the `parent` reference since there is no functionality provided to things such as `parent::parent::etc`.

---

On another note: what you are doing kind of defeats the purpose of inheritance.. *class c* shouldn't be aware of the fact that it's base actually inherits *class a*.

If *class b* wanted *class a*'s constructor to be run it should have implemented this, which yields the fact that if *class c* wants to call *class a*'s constructor it should inherit from *class a*, **not** *class b*.

---

#### Hey, I wanna live on the edge - stop telling me what I cannot do!!one

Well, if you really want to hack your way around this you can explicitly call *class a*'s constructor using the below:

```
class c extends b { 
  public function __construct(){
    a::__construct ();
  }    
}
```

Comment: I think this is much better way of calling A's consturcot in B and Calling B's constructor in C

Answer (score 2):

You can directly call `a::__construct()` from within `c::__construct`, but this is a bad idea.

### Do not do it!

The fact that you feel the need to do it shows that most likely there are serious underlying problems with this class hierarchy. Why would `c` want to bypass the constructor of `b` if `b` was meant to be inherited from?

Comment: Actually, i thought there might be a direct function available in php. Anyways it was a specific requirement... but calling constructor with direct class name may work. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** call parent' constructor in child classes like that:

```
class a{
    public function __construct(){
        echo "<br>In constructor of class A <br>";
    }
}
class b extends a {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        echo "<br>In constructor of class B <br>";
    }
}
class c extends b {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        echo "<br>In constructor of class C <br>";
    }       
}
$obj = new c;
```

That's the way you implement OOP principles. If somehow you need class not to call parent' constructor - this class should be a new base class for another ierarchy, not a child in some tree.
More on constructors: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

Besides agreeing with others, that this is generally a bad practice, I have one more way to do this. You can use the reflection to get the class name of the parent's parent:

```
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($this);
$grandParent = $reflection->getParentClass()->getParentClass()->getName();
$grandParent::__construct();
```